# Why do I get a "The description file for 'AX8108-0110-0105' can not be found." in my TwinCAT Drive Manager 2 project?

Tags: twincat

I have a TwinCAT Drive Manager 2 project with several axis and it worked for some time. However, now when I open the project and select a terminal or a drive I get the following error in the drive manager project:

> No description file
>
> - See TwinCAT Drive Manager 2 output window for more details

[image: drive manager 2 project error]

When I check the output window I see the following

```
INFO | 26/09/2022 10:06:13.543: EtherCATCache fullpath: C:\Users\rruiter\AppData\Roaming\Beckhoff\TwinCAT\3.1\Components\Base\Build_4024.29\EtherCATCache.xml
ERR | 26/09/2022 10:06:13.548: The description file for 'AX8108-0110-0105' can not be found.
INFO | 26/09/2022 10:06:15.668: EtherCATCache fullpath: C:\Users\rruiter\AppData\Roaming\Beckhoff\TwinCAT\3.1\Components\Base\Build_4024.29\EtherCATCache.xml
INFO | 26/09/2022 10:06:16.038: ------ get basic parameters from C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Config\Io\EtherCAT\Beckhoff AX86xx.xml for device AX8620-0000-0103 ------
INFO | 26/09/2022 10:06:16.055: ------ end of getting basic parameters ------
```

How can I get my TwinCAT Drive Manager 2 project to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier way to fix it - in TwinCAT 3, at the top bar, choose TwinCAT. Then click on EtherCAT devices --> update device Description.
Run the process only once. then activate configuration or close TwinCAT and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by reinstalling TwinCAT Drive Manager 2. It turned out that I recently updated to TwinCAT version 4024.32, which apparently removed some config files for 'AX8108-0110-0105'. See below the diff of the files in `C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Config\Io\EtherCAT` after installing 4032 and after reinstalling TwinCAT Drive Manager 2:

```
> git diff --no-index after_install_4032.txt after_reinstall_twincat_drive_manager_2.txt
diff --git a/after_install_4032.txt b/after_reinstall_twincat_drive_manager_2.txt
index b952ef4..fddc373 100644
--- a/after_install_4032.txt
+++ b/after_reinstall_twincat_drive_manager_2.txt
@@ -3,10 +3,10 @@
     Directory: C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Config\Io\EtherCAT


-Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
-----                -------------         ------ ----
-d-----       23/09/2022     14:20                Beckhoff AX5xxx
-d-----       23/09/2022     14:20                RES
+Mode    LastWriteTime         Length Name
+----    -------------         ------ ----
+d-----       26/09/2022     10:19    Beckhoff AX5xxx
+d-----       23/09/2022     14:20    RES
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16        1940011 Beckhoff AMI8xxx.xml
 -a----       31/03/2022     14:50         257759 Beckhoff AMP86xx.xml
 -a----       19/01/2022     16:25         484557 Beckhoff AMP88xx.xml
@@ -15,11 +15,11 @@ d-----       23/09/2022     14:20                RES
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16       10223198 Beckhoff AT2xxx.xml
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16        1523079 Beckhoff ATH2xxx.xml
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16         296705 Beckhoff AX2xxx.xml
--a----       18/02/2022     16:16        1318804 Beckhoff AX5xxx.xml
--a----       18/02/2022     16:16        6936233 Beckhoff AX86xx.xml
--a----       24/05/2022     15:17         362055 Beckhoff AX883x.xml
--a----       18/02/2022     16:16         307413 Beckhoff AX88xx.xml
--a----       18/02/2022     16:16       32531337 Beckhoff AX8yxx.xml
+-ar---       02/06/2022     16:18        1312428 Beckhoff AX5xxx.xml
+-ar---       21/07/2022     11:39        4956612 Beckhoff AX86xx.xml
+-ar---       21/07/2022     11:39         362055 Beckhoff AX883x.xml
+-ar---       21/07/2022     11:39         395079 Beckhoff AX88xx.xml
+-ar---       21/07/2022     11:39       52169060 Beckhoff AX8yxx.xml
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16        1958885 Beckhoff BKxxxx.xml
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16         296057 Beckhoff CUxxxx.xml
 -a----       18/02/2022     16:16         130936 Beckhoff CXxxxx.xml
```